# Counting against a threshold, without knowing the actual count

Tags: algorithm, encryption, counting, bloom-filter

I'm looking for a counting bloom filter kind of data structure that exposes two methods:

```
class ModifiedCountingBloomFilter {
  1. increment()
  2. isThresholdBreached()
}
```

e.g. let's say threshold = 100 users. I'll keep calling increment() every time a user hits my website. And I only want to know whether >=100 users have hit my website.

### Requirements

At any point of time, I shouldn't be able to tell how many users actually visited my website. Just a boolean value of >=100 or <100.

Note that I'm not looking for a class implementation. But an algorithm like bloom-filter that can appropriately hide any counts < 100, i.e. enforces no physical way of obtaining those counts.

### Problems with using `counting bloom filter`

1. I'll be able to tell between 0 and non-zero counts
2. In fact it allows to query for any threshold. I intend to only be able to query for threshold = 100.

### Analogy

It's like an opaque glass of water. I should only be able to add more water to it, and I should only be able to tell if it's full (when the water overflows). Rest everything should be hidden.

Any pointers shall be very appreciated.

Comment: The point of a bloom filter is that you don't have to track individual users, you can tell (with reasonable probability) if you've seen the current user already.  If you don't need that, you can just use a counter.  But either way, the data structure needs to contain the count internally.

Comment: If you want a data structure that can provide an answer and doesn't reveal its internal state, I would suggest looking into homomorphic encryption.

Comment: Sure thanks @btilly, I'll check it out.